# How to read the content from .ppt

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to read the content from .ppt can anyone give me an idea that how i would be able to read the content from power point and simple code would be very much appreciated...

Comment: You should accept some answers to your other questions...

Answer (score 1):

You can use COM automation, here is a tutorial:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303718/en-us

(for Powerpoint 2002, but the concepts are still the same)

Comment: I dont know the object model exactly, but it should be possible to open an existing *.ppt and access the content - please check the docs.